# Stripe invalid_request_error: A token may not be passed in as a Source

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am trying to set payment method on my ecommerce site but the stripe is giving this error: A token may not be passed in as a Source. You can convert your token into a Source using /v1/sources with card[token]=MYTOKEN.

API Side:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payment",(req,res)=> {
    stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        source:req.body.tokenId,
        amount:req.body.amount,
        currency: "usd",
    },(stripeErr,stripeRes)=>{
        if(stripeErr) {
            res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
        }
    })
});


module.exports = router;
```

Client Side:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const makeRequest = async ()=> {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment",{
          tokenId: stripeToken.id,
          amount: cart.total*100,
        });
        history.push("/success",{data: res.data});
      } catch{}
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  },[stripeToken, cart.total, history]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Stripe, [both Tokens and Sources are legacy and deprecated](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/older-apis).  You should be using [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) with Payment Intents instead.

You can [create a Payment Method](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method) instead of a Token, then pass that Payment Method to the Payment Intent using [the `payment_method` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method).

Or, better yet, follow [the accept a payment guide instead](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements), which doesn't require you to handle the Payment Method directly (Stripe.js will take care of it for you when confirming the Payment Intent client-side).